# F# Continuous loop in F#

Tags: asynchronous, f#, task-parallel-library, f#-3.0

I have a socket server that needs to run on a loop accepting clients, so I found out that in funcional programming, a recursive loop is used:

```
let awaitConnections (wsl:WebSocketListener) = 
    let rec loop ()=
        async { 
            let! ws = Async.AwaitTask (wsl.AcceptWebSocketAsync(cancellation.Token) )
            printfn "Connection from %s" (ws.RemoteEndpoint.Address.ToString())
            Async.Start <| awaitMessages ws
            do! loop()}
    loop()
```

And this code is invoked by doing:

```
Async.Start <| awaitConnections listener
```

Considering that the app runs continuously, should I use a iterative approach instead? Does the `rec` approach creates nested execution stacks?

Also, I would like to do something after the loop ends, like:

```
let awaitConnections (wsl:WebSocketListener) = 
    let rec loop ()=
        async { 
            let! ws = Async.AwaitTask (wsl.AcceptWebSocketAsync(cancellation.Token) )
            printfn "Connection from %s" (ws.RemoteEndpoint.Address.ToString())
            Async.Start <| awaitMessages ws
            do! loop()}
    loop()
    printf "The loop ended" // <-- this line
```

But then it cannot compile because the `awaitConnections` return type. How could I do that? Am I doing this right?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You're certainly on the right track! Here is a simple example that demonstrates what you need to do:

```
// Loop that keeps running forever until an exception happens
let rec loop () = async {
  do! Async.Sleep(1000)
  printfn "Working"
  return! loop () }

// Call the loop in a try .. finally block to run some cleanup code at the end
let main () = async {
  try 
    do! loop () 
  finally 
    printfn "That's it!" }

// Start the work in the background and create a cancellation token
let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
Async.Start(main (), cts.Token)
// To cancel it, just call: cts.Cancel()
```

A few important points:

- You cannot really run code after an infinite loop finishes (it is infinite!) but you can use `try .. finally` to run some code when the block is cancelled
- Note that using `return!` for recursive looping is better - using `do!` creates memory leaks.
- You can cancel computation using cancellation token - just pass the token when starting it.

Comment: Thanks! where can I find more information about `return!` vs. `do!` ?

Comment: That's a loaded question, but I'll give it a shot. Computation expressions like `async` are syntactic sugar for a series of function calls, and the return element is the result of the functions. `do!` defines an expression that returns `unit`, which (in this case) basically creates a new `Async<'a>` object that does nothing but go inbetween one recursive call and the next,  `return!` avoids this. Admittedly, this takes some thinking about how `Async` objects work behind the scenes to make everything happen.